# Eclipse - Content Assist not working on objects

Tags: java, eclipse, content-assist

I stopped programming for about a half a year and yesterday I set up my Android Development Environment. The Content Assist functionality isn't working as I want it to.

Here I would expect it to autocomplete the variablename I declared above.
[image: Test]

Here I was expecting to get all the methods I can invoke on a String.
Notice the error in the bottom left, I don't undestand why I get that.
[image: Test2]

Here Content Assist actually works the way it's supposed to.
[image]

I tried it with Eclipse Helios, Indigo and Juno. No idea what the Content Assist is doing there, maybe there is even something wrong with my code?
Edit: I also made a new workspace with no success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dude, you're not in a "code" area; you're trying to code-complete in a *field* area - it's expecting a type.

Try it *inside a method*:

```
public call Test {
    String str_test = "hello world";

    void someMethod() {
        str_tes|... <-- it will complete this
    }
```

[Occam's razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) - choose between:

1. A basic feature of Eclipse doesn't work, yet despite the countless programmers that use Eclipse every day, no one's complained about it or created a bug report, but yet you've discovered it right away
2. Eclipse works just fine and you've just come back to programming from a long break and don't know what you're doing

Comment: Omg, I have forgotten a lot more than I thought!

Answer (score 3):

For the people who come here with the question "How do I pop up content assist automatically, anywhere, for any type/object/field/member":

Such a great answer on [this page](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/post/Eclipse-Content-Assist-Activation-%28Visual-Studio-IntelliSense-Like-Behavior%29.aspx)

Window>preferences>java> content assist

"We found a way to do this with the auto activation preferences in Eclipse.  Simply type in all characters - that is ".abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" - in the Auto activation triggers for Java field. "

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me on the Kepler release on Mac OSX. To restore the functionality I went to:
 Eclipse->Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced 
I checked everything except "word proposals" and "swt template proposals" cause I'm android dev'ing and it doesn't use swt and i'd imagine word proposals means the internal spell checker that keeps underlining all my terribly spelled comments. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. That solved my problem. As a new user on windows I was starting to give up :)